# how do I manually add cookies to WWW::Mechanize's already existing cookiejar

Tags: perl, cookies, mechanize

I have a perl script where after fetching a page I need to add a cookie to an already existing cookiejar with cookies in it already. how do I go about doing this? I'm hoping for a python mechanize style .set_cookie() function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize) object *isa* [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::UserAgent), which has a `cookie_jar` attribute that normally contains a [HTTP::Cookies](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Cookies) object, which has a `set_cookie` method.

So you'd do something like:

```
$mech->cookie_jar->set_cookie( $version, $key, $val, $path, $domain, $port,
                               $path_spec, $secure, $maxage, $discard, \%rest )
```

> The set_cookie() method updates the
>   state of the $cookie_jar. The $key,
>   $val, $domain, $port and $path
>   arguments are strings. The $path_spec,
>   $secure, $discard arguments are
>   boolean values. The $maxage value is a
>   number indicating number of seconds
>   that this cookie will live. A value <=
>   0 will delete this cookie. %rest
>   defines various other attributes like
>   "Comment" and "CommentURL".